не работает конфигурация nvim
вот мой код
local cmp = require 'cmp'
cmp.setup({
    snippet = {
        -- REQUIRED - you must specify a snippet engine
        expand = function(args)
            --vim.fn["vsnip#anonymous"](args.body) -- For `vsnip` users.
            --require('luasnip').lsp_expand(args.body) -- For `luasnip` users.
            --require('snippy').expand_snippet(args.body) -- For `snippy` users.
            --vim.fn["UltiSnips#Anon"](args.body) -- For `ultisnips` users.
        end

    },
    window = {
        completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
        documentation = cmp.config.window.bordered()
    },
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
        ['<C-b>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
        ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
        ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
        ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
        ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({select = true}),
        ["<Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
            if cmp.visible() then
                cmp.select_next_item()
            else
                fallback()
            end
        end, {"i", "s"}),
        ["<S-Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
            if cmp.visible() then
                cmp.select_prev_item()
            else
                fallback()
            end
        end, {"i", "s"})
    }),
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
        {name = 'nvim_lsp'}, {name = 'vsnip'} -- For vsnip users.
    }, {{name = 'buffer'}, {name = 'nvim_lsp_signature_help'}})
})

-- Set configuration for specific filetype.
cmp.setup.filetype('gitcommit', {
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
        {name = 'cmp_git'} -- You can specify the `cmp_git` source if you were installed it.
    }, {{name = 'buffer'}})
})

-- Use buffer source for `/` and `?` (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
cmp.setup.cmdline({'/', '?'}, {
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
    sources = {{name = 'buffer'}}
})

-- Use cmdline & path source for ':' (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
    sources = cmp.config.sources({{name = 'path'}}, {{name = 'cmdline'}})
})

-- Set up lspconfig.
local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()
require('lspconfig')['tsserver'].setup {capabilities = capabilities}

выдает ошибку:

E5113: Error while calling lua chunk:
C:/Users/remne/AppData/Local/nvim/lua/plugins/cmp.lua:67: attempt to
call field 'setup' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
C:/Users/remne/AppData/Local/nvim/lua/plugins/cmp.lua:67: in main
chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
C:\Users\remne\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:12: in main chunk
Обнаружена ошибка при обработке BufReadPost Автокоманды для "":
Error executing lua callback: C:/Program
Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: Error executing lua:
C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:36:
BufReadPost Автокоманды для ""..FileType Автокоманды для "*":
Vim(append):No C compiler found! "cc", "gcc", "clang", "cl", "zig" are
not executable.
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:36: in
function <C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35>
[C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in
function <C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in
function <C:/Program Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
Нажмите ENTER или введите команду для продолжения

помогите что делать то
